# Is it possible to configure a ViewPager to only load off-screen Fragments once the onscreen fragment is rendered?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I currently have a lot of logic that's necessary to show my individual fragments. It might take 300ms to render each individual fragments. 
The ViewPager currently loads the fragment that's visible on screen and the two neighboring fragments before rendering anything in the UI.
I would like it to first render the fragment that's visible to the user and work on the other fragments only once the user got his fragment. Is there a way to get my desired behavior?

Comment: Have u tried with [`mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: @NileshRathod : As far as I can access empirically and logically `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` still gives you the neighboring fragments.

Comment: try doing heavy stuffs in fragments if the fragment is `isVisible()`. This means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window, and (3) is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class

```
override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {    
        PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE    
}
```

Comment: Return position to load next fragment. If you return NONE then nothing to load

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will see a big performance boost here unless you are doing some heavy stuff in the other fragments. But you could always adjust your allowable offscreen after you are done loading whatever your first fragment is loading.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)
```

Then after you are done loading, adjust to how many you want to leave in memory for better user scrolling.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)
```

That should accomplish the behavior you are requesting.